# Can we configure sentry dsn on the worker side instead of the client side?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, backgroundworker, sidekiq, sentry

I have to build a central worker that can have multiple services pushing sentry events to it. Hence every service will have their own dsn, is it possible to configure the dsn on the central worker instead of the client?

Currently I have something like this on the application that will push the event to redis:

```
 Raven.configure do |config|
  configuration = {
    dsn: Figaro.env.sentry_host,
    environments: %w(production),
    sanitize_fields: Rails.application.config.filter_parameters.map(&:to_s),
  }

  config.async = lambda { |event|
    SentryNotifierJob.perform_async(event.to_hash, configuration)
  }

  config.logger = Rails.logger
end
```

and this on the worker:

```
class SentryNotifierJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :retry => true, queue: :default

  def perform(event, config)

    Raven.configure do |config|
      config.dsn = config[:dsn]

      config.sanitize_fields = configuration[:sanitize_fields]

      config.processors = [Raven::Processor::SanitizeData]
      config.sanitize_fields.push('Authorization', 'tokenId', 'Client-Id', 'Pass-Key', 'gcmKey', 'deviceToken')

      config.logger = Rails.logger
    end
    Raven.send_event(event)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer, yes it is possible to configure the sentry dsn from the worker instead of client side. Raven does not care where the config is updated.